# Best way to speed up requests using date columns

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

Our database is receiving the following requests:

```
select * from [schema].[table] (nolock) where (Date_A > Date_B and Archive = 0)
```

This is a normal request that is made by our application. On average, the request is taking between 200ms - 400ms to complete, with about 100ms - 150ms in CPU. Reads normally come in at about 48k. This is at least one example of how this script performs.

What would be the best way (if there is a way) to speed up this type of request?

The table has 240,932 rows and the queries return 0 records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is only a small subset of rows with `Archive = 0`, you could use a filtered index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Archive_Filtered
    ON [schema].[table] ([Date_A], [Date_B])
    INCLUDE ([Archive])
    WHERE ([Archive] = 0)
```

*Note: I've made the index on the two date fields only because I don't know of any other fields in your table - it might make more sense for this to be on a different field*

*Additional Note: always take care to include the filtering columns in the filtered index keys or included columns, so here for one example of why: [Incorrect row estimation given with a filtered index](https://answers.sqlperformance.com/questions/336/incorrect-row-estimation-given-with-a-filtered-ind.html)*

This keeps the index small (which means it uses less storage, and is quicker to read from), because only the rows where Archive is 0 are included in it.

If a filtered index won't work for you (and there are a number of scenarios where they don't work, see [Filtered Indexes and Dynamic SQL](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/11/filtered-indexes-and-dynamic-sql/) for one example), you could try a normal nonclustered index on the archive field OR the date fields.  You would want to create the index on whichever field is most *selective* - meaning which one will narrow down the results the most.

For instance, again if only a small subset of your rows have an Archive value of 0, you could create this index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Archive_Includes
    ON [schema].[table] ([Archive])
    INCLUDE ([Date_A], [Date_B])
```

This will let your query seek to the correct rows (where Archive is 0), and then filter easily on Date_A and Date_B.

Additional comments about your query:

- you really shouldn't use `select *` - enumerate each of the fields you actually need in your results to be more efficient, and allow more effective indexing
- you shouldn't use `nolock` if the accuracy of the results is important

  - see this post for a quick demo of how results can be wrong with nolock: [Using NOLOCK? Here’s How You’ll Get the Wrong Query Results](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/10/using-nolock-heres-how-youll-get-the-wrong-query-results/)
  - see this post for a lot more detail about using nolock (which is the same as the read uncommitted isolation level): [The Read Uncommitted Isolation Level](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/04/t-sql-queries/the-read-uncommitted-isolation-level)